# Angular - How to map object recieved by httpClient.request() to an Interface in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an object I recieve from a Method in the backend part, that I call with `httpClient.request()`

```
this.httpClient.request<YearlyOverview[]>('get', `${this.configService.get('serverMethodsUrl')}api/ServerMethods/getPresencesByEmployeeIdAndYear`, {
    withCredentials: true,
    params: new HttpParams().set('userId', '292')
                            .set('year', '2019')
  }).subscribe((result: any) => {
            myArray = result;
  });
```

the object that is returned, looks like this:

```
myArray: 
  [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "Mike",
    presences: [
                    {
                        month: 1,
                        current: 50,
                        total: 170,
                        days: [
                                {day: 1, total: 8.5},
                                {day: 2, total: 8.5},
                                {day: 3, total: 8.5},
                                {day: 4, total: 8.5},
                                .............
                            ]
                    }
                ]
    }
  ]
```

So basically, there are 3 nested Arrays.

Just to give you an idea, it shows all the working hours, for each day, for a selected Employee.

Meanwhile my Interface is slightly different, the biggest difference is that the third Array is not present, it has the `"days"` array included in the `"presences"` one:

```
export interface YearlyOverview {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  presences: Array<YearlyPresence>;
}

export interface YearlyPresence {
  month: number;
  current: number;
  total: number;
  day1: number;
  day2: number;
  day3: number;
  day4: number;
  day5: number;
  day6: number;
  day7: number;
  ...and so on up to day31
}
```

Now I'm trying to map the object I recieve from the HttpClient, to my Interface, but I need some help. Who can point me in the right direction?

I would like to map to "day1" of my Interface, the value of "total" for that day.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I dont test it, but something like that

```
this.httpClient.request<YearlyOverview[]>('get', `${this.configService.get('serverMethodsUrl')}api/ServerMethods/getPresencesByEmployeeIdAndYear`, {
    withCredentials: true,
    params: new HttpParams().set('userId', '292')
        .set('year', '2019')
}).pipe(
    map(values => values.map(year => {
        year.presences = year.presences.map(presence => {
            presence.days.forEach(day => presence['day' + day.day] = day.total)
        })
    }))
    )
    .subscribe((result: YearlyOverview[]) => {
        myArray = result;
    });
```

Comment: Because they are used elsewhere as well, we could change how the object is returned by that http call, but that would require some pivoting and so on, but anyway, let's say I match the return object with my interface, now how can I correctly map it? I'm missing that part

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still not sure I know what to do inside the map method. Like I thought it would be done on the result of the subscribe, not before, so how can I assign each value of the return object, to a new Array, of type YearlyOverview, on the correct properties? If you could provide a partial example with my dummy data provided above, just to see how to proceed, Thank you

Comment: I write something fast :) so i dont test it. But something like that